# useState Reactjs not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use React Hooks but somehow my state is not updating

```
  const [Choices, setChoices] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUsers() {
      // Here’s the magic
      let tempChoices = [];
      const promises = MAINLIST.List.ChoicesFields.map(async z => {
        tempChoices[z] = [];

        let GetChoicesFromInternalFieldResults = await GetChoicesFromInternalField(
          z
        );
        GetChoicesFromInternalFieldResults.map(c => {
          tempChoices[z].push({
            key: c,
            text: c,
            value: c
          });
        });
      });
      await Promise.all(promises);
      const object = { Choices: tempChoices };
      // THIS IS PRINTING CORRECT VALUES
      console.log(object);
      setChoices(object);
    }
    getUsers();
  }, []);
```

Here is the console.log result

[image]

but when I check the state in the developer tool the state is empty

[image]

Comment: And the array you logging is empty either

Comment: Why its empty I am logging it and it has 3 value on it

Comment: I see an `Array(0)` with `length:0` as expected in `devTools`

Answer (score 0):

I found my answers. I made "tempChoices" into an array instead of an object.

```
  const [Choices, setChoices] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUsers() {
      // Here’s the magic
      let tempChoices = {};
      const promises = MAINLIST.List.ChoicesFields.map(async z => {
        tempChoices[z] = [];

        let GetChoicesFromInternalFieldResults = await GetChoicesFromInternalField(
          z
        );
        GetChoicesFromInternalFieldResults.map(c => {
          tempChoices[z].push({
            key: c,
            text: c,
            value: c
          });
        });
      });
      await Promise.all(promises);
      const object = { Choices: tempChoices };

      setChoices(object);
    }
    getUsers();
  }, []);
```